# How to achive YouTube-like Video Playback in Web Apps?

Tags: file-upload, html5-video, loading

My video platform currently loads all of the video content at once before it starts playing. How can I make it load the video in smaller chunks as the user watches it, like YouTube does?

```
<div class="main_video_player">
  <video controls width="100%" height="auto" poster="<?php echo $thumbnail_path; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $video_url; ?>">
    <source src="<?php echo $video_url; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

It is loading whole video at once and then it start playing the video thats the main problem.
I want video starts playing immediately. Heres the code of the video storing :

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

// Function to generate a random video ID (link)
function generate_random_id($length = 10) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $random_id = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $random_id .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $random_id;
}

// Function to check if the generated video_id exists in the database
function is_video_id_exists($video_id, $conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM videos WHERE video_id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $video_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $count = $row['count'];
    $stmt->close();
    return $count > 0;
}
// Function to send video content with byte range support
function send_video_content($video_url) {
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');

    $video_file_size = filesize($video_url);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        list($size_unit, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if ($size_unit === 'bytes') {
            list($range_start, $range_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);
            $range_start = intval($range_start);
            $range_end = intval($range_end);
        }
    } else {
        $range_start = 0;
        $range_end = $video_file_size - 1;
    }

    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Content-Length: ' . ($range_end - $range_start + 1));
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range_start-$range_end/$video_file_size");

    $video_file = fopen($video_url, 'rb');
    fseek($video_file, $range_start);
    echo fread($video_file, $range_end - $range_start + 1);
    fclose($video_file);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Validate form data
    if (isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["category"]) && isset($_FILES["video_file"]) && isset($_POST["thumbnail_data"])) {
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $category = $_POST["category"];
        $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        // Generate a random video ID (link)
        $video_id = generate_random_id(10);

        // Check if the generated video_id already exists in the database
        
        while (is_video_id_exists($video_id, $conn)) {
            $video_id = generate_random_id(10);
        }

        // File upload handling for video
        $target_dir = "../uploads/";
        $video_filename = $video_id . ".mp4";
        $video_url = $target_dir . $video_filename;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $videoFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["video_file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // Check if the video file is valid
        $maxFileSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 MB in bytes

        if ($_FILES["video_file"]["size"] > $maxFileSize) {
            echo "Error: Video file is too large. Maximum file size is 500 MB.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Allow only specific video file formats (you can add more if needed)
        if ($videoFileType !== "mp4" && $videoFileType !== "avi" && $videoFileType !== "mov") {
            echo "Error: Only MP4, AVI, and MOV video formats are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // If the file upload is valid, move the video to the uploads folder
        if ($uploadOk) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video_file"]["tmp_name"], $video_url)) {
                // Get the thumbnail data
                $thumbnail_data = $_POST["thumbnail_data"];

                // Decode the base64-encoded thumbnail data
                $thumbnail_data_decoded = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $thumbnail_data));

                // Generate a random filename for the thumbnail
                $thumbnail_filename = generate_random_id(10) . ".jpg";

                // Set the path to save the thumbnail on the server
                $thumbnail_path = "../thumbnails/" . $thumbnail_filename;

                // Create an image resource from the decoded thumbnail data
                $thumbnail = imagecreatefromstring($thumbnail_data_decoded);

                // Set the desired thumbnail width and height (e.g., 200x200)
                $thumbnail_width = 640;
                $thumbnail_height = 360;

                // Create a new thumbnail with the desired size using GD library
                $thumbnail_resized = imagescale($thumbnail, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);

                // Save the resized thumbnail to the server with a lower quality setting
                imagejpeg($thumbnail_resized, $thumbnail_path, 80); 

                // Free up memory
                imagedestroy($thumbnail);
                imagedestroy($thumbnail_resized);

                // Prepare and execute the SQL query to save video and thumbnail information
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (video_id, title, category, video_url, thumbnail_url, user_ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $video_id, $title, $category, $video_filename, $thumbnail_filename, $user_ip);

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    // Insertion successful, create the video link
                    $video_link = "http://localhost/new/hub/#/video?video_id=" . $video_id;

                    // Construct the response data as an associative array
                    $response = array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => "Video uploaded complete",
                        'video_link' => $video_link,
                        'category' => $category, // Include category in the response
                        'thumbnail_url' => $thumbnail_filename,
                    );

                    
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');

                    // Send the JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
                }

                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                echo "Error: Failed to upload the video.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: Missing form fields!";
    }
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your MP4 seems to have it's metadata, called a MOOV box, put at the back of the file (so it must now fully download before it can be playable). MOOV tells the video player which bytes is for the first frame etc. To fix you need a tool. Search on Google for keywords `mp4 moov front fix`. Or use FFmpeg if you know it.

Comment: PS: If this was my problem, I would just download FFmpeg and then use it to produce a **fragmented MP4** (it can be one long file or separate chunks). Then seeking now means just getting (or `echo`) the bytes of the chunk that is nearest to the requested seek time.